# Apache BeanUtils.copyProperties is spilling too much log

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons-beanutils

How can I switch off logging for BeanUtils.copyProperties ? It creates way too much logs and hampers the log file readability. Thanks heaps..

Sample code

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(someDataobject,someActionForm);
```

In the log I see hunders of lines like below

> EBUG org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils  - setSimpleProperty:
>    Invoking method public void someMethod(java.lang.String) with value null (class )
>   2010-03-23 18:53:23,134 DEBUG org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils  -     copyProperty(someActionForm@13e38a7, someValue, )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you can configure the logging level of each class individually. This depends a bit on which logging framework you are using but adding something like the following to your logging configuration file:

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.level=SEVERE
```

Should restrict the logger in that class to only output SEVERE logging statements.

You can also silence the entire package with

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.level=SEVERE
```

If you want more details, you'll have to provide more context.

Comment: Apache log4j supports only TRACE,DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERROR and FATAL levels. Can you please update your answers, I don't have reps to edit it :(

Answer (score 0):

If you used log4j you can use

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils=ERROR
```

more details
[see log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

As for me using Commons BeanUtils in Spring Boot project, I found working solution to be JCL-over-SLF4J replacement, as in this link:
[Logging Dependencies in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/)